# The operator $D^{p}\colon \mathcal{S}\subset L^{1}(\gamma)\to L^{1}(\gamma)$ is closable for every integer $p =1,2,\dots$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability

I am reading Nourdin and Peccati’s textbook (Normal Approximations with Malliavin Calculus From Stein’s Method to Universality). My question is about Lemma 1.1.6. Which says

**Lemma 1.1.6**:
The operator $D^{p}\colon \mathcal{S}\subset L^{q}(\gamma)\to L^{q}(\gamma)$ is closable for every $q\in[1,\infty)$ and every integer $p\geq 1$.

Here $\mathcal{S}$ is the space of $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ such that $f$ and all its derivatives have at most polynomial growth.

In case someone doesn’t remember, here is the definition of closable. A linear operator $A\colon D(A)\subset \mathcal{B}\to \mathcal{B}$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is a Banach space is closable if it has a closed extension. The following characterization might also be useful:

The operator is closable iff for every sequence $\{f_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset D(A)$ such that $f_{n}\to 0$ and $Af_{n}\to g$, then we have $g=0$.

My question is the following. How does one prove this lemma when $q=1$? When $q\geq 1$, Holder’s inequality helps. But if $q=1$ the same trick doesn’t apply! The authors say it needs some specific argument which uses the $(L^{1}(\gamma))’=L^{\infty}(\gamma)$. Here $\gamma$ is the Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}$, given by
$
\gamma(A)=\int_{A}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}dx$.

Comment: And $Df=f'$, I suppose?

Comment: If my interpretation of the question is correct, I don't think there's anything special involved: if $f_n\to 0$, $f'_n\to g$ in $L^1$, then also $f_n\to 0$ pointwise a.e. on a subsequence, so $f_n(x)=f_n(a)+\int_a^x f'_n(t)\, dt\to \int_a^x g(t)\, dt$. This shows that $\int_a^b g=0$ for all $a,b$, so $g=0$. This is the case $p=1$, $q\ge 1$, and a similar argument should work for any $p$.

Comment: This follows from a standard argument which also identifies the closure.  Your operator is also continuous and linear on the dual of $\cal S$, the space of tempered distributions and so the graph of the latter is closed. Hence so is its intersection with the product of the $L^q$ spaces.  The resulting operator is then determined by its domain of definition-- those $L^q$ functions $f$ which are such that $D^pf$ (distributional derivative) lies in $L^q$.